# Javascript + Google Tag Manager prints hyphens in my website

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am a web developer of an e-commerce website. I added google tag manager and I have to use it. But there is a problem about it.

When I add it to header, it creates lots of hyphens (usually in footer sometimes header - probably about loading time of js).

[flavus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIJGJ.png)

I tried this google tag manager in my localhost website and there are hyphens again. What should I do help me please :/

[hyphens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8whFM.png)

Comment: Please add relevant code snippets in the question, not in images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have custom html tags that contain the hyphens.

While this is obvious without looking, it can be confirmed by looking at your gtm.js file.

[image: unwanted characters in html code]

Apparently, when you copied your tracking code, you copied some hyphens that were only there to separate the code from the surrounding text.

When you want to run Javascript via custom HTML tags, you need to make sure everything is wrapped in `<script>` tags (and is valid javascript). Any character outside script tags will just become visible at the page bottom (GTM appends all custom HTML tags to the page bottom).

Go to the GTM interface, look through the custom HTML tags and delete the hyphens. Save, and publish.

Comment: thanks for helps man, I added just this script to my header

`
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-T4L2TJK');</script>
`

this hyphens coming from gtm.js but how can I edit it?

Comment: GTM is a software by Google that you can log in to to configure and edit tags - it then deploys the tags within a website. If you do not know that, and haven't configured the tags yourself, then I urge to remove the GTM snippet, because whoever owns the GTM account that belongs to that ID has now full control over your website, because he can run arbitrary Javascript.

Comment: we are working with an agency for these jobs like ads or gtm. It is our gtm account. Our agency could not fix this. What should I do in google tag manager panel to fix this idiot issue :(

Comment: You should start by firing your agency, who apparently does not know how to use GTM. Like I wrote, you have to log in to the GTM account, select "tags" from the left hand menu, then open every tag of the type "Custom HTML". At least one of them will contain lots of hyphens in addition to the script that was meant to be deployed there. Delete the hyphens, save the tag, repeat for any other custom HTML tag, and publish your container. This is not Google's fault, this is a user error.

Comment: Thank you so much my man! I will want permission and apply your advice. I will share your firing advice with boss :)